# Boot camp partition lost

Tags: boot-camp

I tried to use boot camp assistant to set up a 120gb partition for windows on my mac (500gb hard drive)

The issue was that the computer crashed during the partition process and now the hard drive is showing up as 460 gb (not 500) and the free space on it is around 140gb less than it used to be in spite of the fact that the second partition isn't showing up.

I have no idea where the space went now.

Is there any way that I can recover this space and try again with bootcamp short of reformatting my entire hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Open up disk utility in /Applications/Utilities and use it to extend your Mac partition to all 500gb again. Once that is done, try BootCamp Setup Assistant again.

[image: Recovering Partitions]

Comment: I restarted and the hd is again appearing as 500gb in disk utility but the available space is still showing up as 75gb instead of the 215 that I had before.  Any idea what to do about this?

Comment: You might want to boot into your OS installation disc and run Disk Utility from there. Running it from the disc should allow the system to reallocate the hard drive space caused by hidden temporary partitions. You could also boot into a linux live cd and use its partition manager to fix your hard drive. If this still doesn't fix the problem, back up your system with Time Machine and reformat the entire drive.